# how to update database schema after running migrations in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

I'm starting with Ruby on Rails and I have these two models:

City and Street,

These two models were generated independently with no relation between them. Now I need a city to have many streets and each street to belong to a single city. I ran this command:

`bin/rails generate migration AddCityRefToStreets city:references`

That generated this migration:

```
class AddCityRefToStreets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :streets, :city, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Then I ran `bin/rails db:migrate` and then I went into these model classes and wrote:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :streets, dependant: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Street < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :city
end
```

Rails did not show any complains, and so far it works fine for me. If I ask `@city.streets.length` it will return the correct amount of streets for that `@city`. If I ask `@street.city` it returns the correct city as well.

The thing is, I went into the database using DBeaver and the migration did not generate relations between the `cities` and `streets` tables. The `streets` table shows me a `city_id` field, but still not showing any relationship in the ER Diagram view.

My question is: what am I missing here? Is this the correct way to relate two entities created independently?

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3, Rails 5.2.1, Sqlite 3.11.0 and DBeaver 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_reference` migration command will have added a `city_id` column to your `streets` table.

When you call `@city.streets`, it is evaluated as the equivalent of `Street.where(city_id: @city.id)`.

Similarly, `@street.city` will look at the ID stored in `city_id` column, and do a lookup - the equivalent of `City.find(@street.city_id)`.

Comment: in other words: the application will maintain the referential identity instead of the database?

Comment: A bit of both. The `foreign_key: true` line in the `add_reference` migration command tells the underlying database that the column it's adding should be considered a foreign key.

Comment: Not being able to use paragraphs always gets me in SO comments…) ActiveRecord will do its best to ensure integrity – `belongs_to` relationships are validated by default and can't be nullified unless you specify `optional: true` when you define the relationship in your model. You may also want to ensure that you've spelled `dependent: :destroy` correctly in your `has_many` declaration, or ActiveRecord will silently ignore it. And if Rails is your only way into the database, that's often "good enough" for small projects.

Comment: To be safe, though, the `foreign_key: true` clause of the migration command that created the reference column should tell the database to enforce its own restrictions to make sure that all values in `streets.city_id` are valid (more information on the [SQLite site](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)). That's especially useful if other apps might be creating data.

Comment: if migrations doesn't create relations in the database then each table will be a lonely entity

Comment: The relationships are there (as defined by the foreign key), but I think you're expecting your database viewer to visualise them as some form of explicit entity in their own right, and in the world of SQLite (or indeed, PostgreSQL or MySQL) that's not common.